# How to delete specific files from terminal

Tags: command-line, delete

Recently, I converted my music files to a different format. I have for example a folder of an artist containing the different albums in separate folders. I would knowing if is there a way to delete *.mp3 files in all my album folders of an artist using a simple command? For example, if I use `~music/artist_a/album1$rm *.mp3` it delete all the mp3 files of only the folder album1, but I want to use a command that delete all the mp3's of album1, album2,... in the artist_a folder.

Thanks!

Comment: I would be very interested in an answer myself. Surprisingly, the `-r` option for `rm` only removes files in the top-level directory.

Comment: Jeje, I try to use, for example ´rm -r *.mp3´ but it's BAD X)

Comment: @WarriorIng64: given that the `*` expansion is done by the shell, `rm` only see a list of names, and delete them. If one of these names is a directory, the `-r` would indicate to remove the whole directory.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you go one level up, you can do:

```
~music/artist_a/album1$ cd ..
~music/artist_a$ rm */*.mp3
```

to delete mp3s from every directory inside the current. If you want to delete only from specific subdirectories:

```
~music/artist_a$ rm {album1,album2,album4}/*.mp3
```

You can also use `find` to delete all mp3 in subfolders of every level

```
~music/artist_a$ find . -iname '*.mp3' -delete
```

Use these command with caution.

Comment: Excellent information! All works OK. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

An alternative method you could use would be

```
find ~music/artist_a -name \*.mp3 -exec rm {} \;
```

([Source](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/129/recursively-delete-certain-files/))

Comment: I found this solution is better if you want to delete files into a indefinite number of directories. It's a excellent solution and more general.